# After repeating a value n times, insert a fixed value(s), then increase the original value by a % and repeat process

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to do the following WITHOUT VBA. I have most of this working using MOD/column formulas, but cannot get it to include both the growth of cells and fixed values at the same time:

EDIT:
Responses have been amazing so far, thank you for that! Unfortunately, I left one thing out:
I want to have another variable, call it M, which indicates how many values will appear before the next "F" value appears. So while I want the starting value to grow after repeating N times (and repeat that), I do not always want the Fixed Value (F) to appear after each growth.

**Variables:**

X: Starting Value

N: Repeat same value this # of times before growth occurs

F: Actual Fixed Value to appear after (M) # of values

M: Number of values that appear between each Fixed Value (F)

FS: # of Times Fixed Value (F) appears BEFORE Starting Value (X) first appears (if the beginning needs to be offset with the Fixed Value once or multiple times)

FN: # of Times Fixed Value Appears each time

G: Value Growth (after same value repeats N times and the fixed value(s) (F) appear, the next value will be the previous value increased by G%)

Example 1:
X: 10
N: 5
F: BLUE
M: 5
FS: 1
FN: 1
G: 100%

Output: BLUE, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, BLUE, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, BLUE, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, BLUE, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80

Example 2:
X: 10
N: 3
F: BLUE
M: 6
FS: 0
FN: 1
G: 100%

Output: 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, BLUE, 40, 40, 40, 80, 80, 80, BLUE, 160, 160, 160

Example 3:
X: 10
N: 2
F: BLUE
M: 6
FS: 3
FN: 2
G: 100%

Output: BLUE, BLUE, BLUE, 10, 10, 20, 20, 40, 40, BLUE, BLUE, 80, 80, 160, 160, 320, 320, BLUE, BLUE

I know this likely complicates things, and I really appreciate the feedback guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(COLUMN(A:A)<=$D2, $C2, IF(MOD(SUM(COLUMN(A:A), -$D2, -1), SUM($B2, $E2))<$B2, $A2*$F2*POWER(2, FLOOR(SUM(COLUMN(A:A), -$D2)/SUM($B2, $E2), 1)), $C2))
```

[image]

Comment: beautiful..................................

Comment: Can you tell just how bored I am this lovely Sunday afternoon?

Comment: To me, Excel is way more fun than sudoku

Comment: nice answer, I'm trying to figure out the the "SPILL" ability in the newer excel and modified the formula to: `=IF(COLUMN(A:S)<=$D3, $C3, IF(MOD(COLUMN(A:S)-$D3-1, SUM($B3, $E3))<$B3, $A3*$F3*POWER(2, FLOOR((COLUMN(A:S)-$D3)/SUM($B3, $E3), 1)), $C3))`. You just put that in column A and it will automatically spill out to column S. I'm too lazy to incorporate the indirect function to make it spill to any desired length.